# i tried many times, but it's throwing an error

Tags: javascript

Question is:

> Write a function which takes a sentence as an input and output a
> sorted sentence.
>
> 1. Each character of the word should be arranged in alphabetical order
> 2. Words should be arranged in ascending order depending on its character count
>
> Note: - Word only can have lowercase letters
>
> Example :
>
> Inputs str = "she lives with him in a small apartment"
>
> Output = "a in ehs him hitw eilsv allms aaemnprtt"

the error is

> // running test
> "message: The answer should be valid for any given input."
> // tests completed

my code:

```js
function makeAlphabetSentenceSort(str) {
  str.toLowerCase();
  var word = str.split(' ');
  for (var j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {
    word[j] = word[j].split('').sort().join('');
  }
  for (var h = 0; h < word.length - 1; h++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < word.length - h - 1; i++) {
      if (String(word[i]).length > String(word[i + 1]).length) {
        var temp = word[i];
        word[i] = word[i + 1];
        word[i + 1] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
  return word.join(' ');
}

console.log(makeAlphabetSentenceSort("she lives with him in a small apartment"));
console.log(makeAlphabetSentenceSort("she lives with him in apartment"));
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me and provides the expected result

Comment: Are you sure expected output shouldn't be: `a in ehs him hitw allms eilsv aaemnprtt`?

Comment: `str.toLowerCase();` doesn't do anything if you don't assign the result. But it's not needed because the description says that the input only contains lowercase characters.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the `word.sort()` to order the words in length order?

Comment: @BeRT2me The problem description doesn't say anything about how words with the same length should be ordered, so both should be OK.

Comment: Why do you need to call `String()`? The elements of `word` are already strings.

Comment: Half of dealing with the BS of taking a programing course is interpreting the unspoken rules and mistakes of the material. They both *should* be OK, but that doesn't mean much :') @Barmar

Comment: I suspect the problem is an off-by-one error in the loop that's trying to sort the results by length. I'm not sure if the limits in the `for` loops are correct.

Comment: +1. This is why using `words.map(word => word.split('').sort()).sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length)` (consider pseudo) might be useful as it simplifies the code and makes these kind of errors more apparent.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an exercise from a course so I won't give you the exact implementation but I will say this:

JavaScript has some nice abstractions that will help.

**Arrays**

use [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

- `"my string".split(' ')` to make an array of words.
- `"someword".split('')` to make an array of characters.

**Arrays can be iterated**

Use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate through an array and return something for each item.

**Arrays can be sorted**

Use [`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to do any sorting of arrays.

Comment: It's not just the methods I'm pointing out (but also how to approach them). The implementation can be simplified by a lot. For loops are what are making it complicated for new developers.

Comment: It's not meant as a code review, but to help the topic starter solve their problem effectively. Personally I believe this is a useful answer but as you prefer; I see I'm heavily outranked.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
function makeAlphabetSentenceSort(str) {
var word = str.split(' ');
  for (var j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {
    word[j] = word[j].split('').sort().join('');
  }
  return word.sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length).join(' ');
}
console.log(makeAlphabetSentenceSort('he was curious about how it would taste, so he took a small bite.'));
```

The problem with that question is that they do not follow their own rules which states:

> Word only can have lowercase letters

that said a sentence with punctuation could run through the code.

So, to be able to pass this challenge, you're also going to need to swap words of the same length with each other.

Comment: How do you know they're not following their rules?

Comment: Just from the question and the error that he is getting back, I supposed that if it is only lower case letters. then the only thing that would be in the sentence other than lower case is the punctuation. which is going to provide  him with valid answers for all inputs.. that is just my guess tho.